# Using grep to search for line that begins with a variable whose value is a dollar sign

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, grep, special-characters

I found a lot of very similar problems, but not exactly this.
I have a text file with the following contents (no repeats, fixed 4 characters per line):

```
A1234
G1234
$1234
M1234
```

I'm trying to use grep to search for a line that begins with the character $char that's been input by using $char to define the search terms, and assign the four numbers after it to $numbr.  Here's what it looks like:

```
numbr=`grep ^"${char}" file.txt | cut -c 2,3,4,5`
```

This works for any character I need, except for dollar signs, which leave $numbr empty.

The input character $char is defined beforehand as follows, if that helps:

```
char="`dd if=text.txt ibs=1 skip=$skipcount count=1`"
```

($skipcount is an integer)

I tried with and without -E flag, and every way of escaping the value of $char I could find.  I don't need to use grep specifically, I just had the most success with it so far.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Apologies if I managed to duplicate a post, and thanks to all who contribute here, I've found a solution to almost every problem within a minute or two.

Edit: Sorry to the guy whose comment I accidentally deleted.  The gist was he suggested echo and pipe, something like this (I assumed this was partial and I needed to fill in the rest):

```
echo "${char}" | grep '^\$'
```

Wasn't working for me.  I also wasn't clear enough - in each string in the .txt (ex. A1234), only the first character is what's assigned to $char.  The 4 numbers after $char is what I need assigned to $numbr, and that string can occur at any line in the .txt file.  There will be no other bytes on each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*<sup>1</sup>

In your case, the two problems are:

1. the `$` character is special in some contexts in your shell
2. the `$` character is special in some contexts in regular expressions

In the case of `perl`, there's a third problem - again that `$` is special in some contexts - which is why the trick of wrapping the shell variable expansion in brackets `[${char}]` works in a double-quoted `sed` expression, but not in a similar double-quoted `perl` expression (since the latter results in perl expanding `$]` as [the revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%24%5D)).

---

So you want your shell to expand `${char}` (or `$char`) to its value `$` but for neither the shell nor the tool you're using to further expand `$`. [The comprehensive answer by @Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502289/178692) shows you some ways to achieve that.

One quirk of GNU grep is that in [Basic Regular Expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) mode (i.e. without either the `-E` or `-P` command line switch), the `$` end-of-line anchor is **only** special when it occurs at the end of an expression. So whereas `^$` matches only empty lines, `^$[[:digit:]]\{4\}` or even `^$.` will match `$` literally. So given your example `file.txt`, either

```
$ grep "^${char}[[:digit:]]\{4\}" file.txt | cut -c 2-
1234
```

or more simply

```
$ grep ^"${char}". file.txt | cut -c 2-
1234
```

would have given you the desired output. However, since you don't appear to need to check that the string after the `$` is actually 4 digits, you could equally well use `cut` alone<sup>2</sup>:

```
$ cut -sd "${char}" -f2 file.txt
1234
```

This avoids *both* problems by doing away with regular expressions altogether and treating the task as a simple string splitting one. Similarly with `awk`<sup>3</sup>:

```
$ awk -F "${char}" 'NF>1 {print $2}' file.txt
1234
```

Note that neither of these anchors the `$` match to the start of the line - if you need to do that, then a non-regex way to do so in awk might be

```
awk 'index($0,ENVIRON["char"]) == 1 {print substr($0,2)}' file.txt
```

where the `ENVIRON` array similar to perl's `ENV` hash requires you to export `$char`, but allows you to *single-quote* the expression - thus avoiding "problem #1" altogether.

---

1. see [What is meant by "Now you have two problems"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)
2. this assumes the GNU implementation of `cut`, with its `-s, --only-delimited` command line option
3. a *single character* field separator is not treated as a regular expression in awk

Comment: And it turns out simple solutions require a deeper knowledge and a creative mind ... So, how come they get called "simple" :-) ... Take that as an off-topic friendly complement that is actually earned.

Comment: Thank you sir, I was having some confusion about expressions and this is very helpful.  I truly appreciate the time you took to guide me.  Have a great day!

Comment: $ grep ^"${char}". file.txt | cut -c 2-        is what I ended up using, and it fixed almost all of my downstream issues so thanks again.  Took me a hot minute to notice the "dot" in there after "${char}" though lol.

Answer (score 6):

`$` has a special meaning in RegEx (end of the line) ... So, to match it litterlally, it needs to be stripped of that special meaning by e.g. escaping it with a backslash `\` ... To do that dynamically, you can use Bash's parameter expansion like `${char/\$/\\$}`:

```
grep -Po "^${char/\$/\\$}\K[[:digit:]]+" file.txt
```

... where:

- `grep`'s options `-Po` will enable **P**erl style regular expressions (needed for `\K`) and **o**nly print the matching capturing group(s).
- `^` will match the beginning of a line.
- `${char/\$/\\$}` inside the double quotes `" ... "` will be expanded by the shell (Bash) to the variable `char` replacing the first occurrence (from the left) of `$` (if it's found) with `\$` i.e. passing it to the command line with an escape character before it so that it gets matched literally later by `grep`.<sup>**1**</sup>
- Perl's `\K` will exclude the matched part on its left-side from printing (will reset the match at that point) that's so only the right-side match of it i.e. `[[:digit:]]+` will be printed ... Still the whole expression left-side and right-side will be evaluated and have to match in an input line in that sequence.
- `[[:digit:]]+` will match a number `[[:digit:]]` (any kind UNICODE included) at least once `+`.

<sup>**1**) For other shells that do not support Bash's `${var/find/replace}` kind of parameter expansion, you can use normal parameter expansion inside square brackets like `[${char}]` as when that parameter expands inside `[]`, the resulting character e.g. `$` will be treated litteral.</sup>

... and use it in your variable assignment like so:

```
numbr=$(grep -Po "^${char/\$/\\$}\K[[:digit:]]+" file.txt)
```

**Notice** the old notation for command substitution i.e. backticks "`...`" is a legacy compatibility feature now and is deprecated in favor of the current command substitution notation `$(...)` ... So, use the latter.

---

Other none `grep` solutions (for more portability as `grep`'s `-P` option might not be present/supported in all implementation) include:

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"${char}" '$2~"^[[:digit:]]+$" {print $2}' file.txt
```

... where the field separator is set to `${char}` and then if the second field is all numbers `$2~"^[[:digit:]]+$"`, then print it `print $2`.

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE "s/^([${char}])([[:digit:]]+)$/\2/p" file.txt
```

... where `-nE` will default to **n**o printing and enable **E**xtended regular expressions to handle e.g. `[]` and capture groups `()` and then the double quotes `"..."` around the script string will allow for parameter expansion by the shell so that `${char}` get expanded to its value and if the regular expression matches in a line then the matched numbers get assigned to the second capturing group i.e. `([[:digit:]]+)` and called by its reference number `\2` to substitute the whole match and then gets printed with the command `p`.

With `perl`:

```
export char; perl -lne 'print $1 if /^\Q$ENV{char}\E(\d+)$/' file.txt
```

... where `-n` defaults to **n**o printing and `print $1` will print the first capturing group in `(...)` i.e. `(\d+)` (short for `([[:digit:]]+)`) if the RegEx match.

**Notice** the `export char` in order to call that variable as an environment variable from the Perl script between `\Q` and `\E` and that's to properly handle the RegEx when `char` expands to `$` and [`$]`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%24%5D) might not work ... Otherwise, something like the following should work if `$` isn't part of the RegEx:

```
perl -lne "/(?<=^[${char}])([[:digit:]]+)$/ and print $&" file.txt
```

... where `-n` defaults to **n**o printing and the double quotes `"..."` will allow shell parameter expansion to happen and the lookbehind `(?<=...)` will match but in a none-capturing (none printing) group and `print $&` will print the match from capturing group(s).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'll get to work using your input.  Cheers!

Comment: @Aylox You're welcome ... Notice, you don't need `| cut -c 2,3,4,5` anymore.

Comment: Works perfectly.  I appreciate you spelling it out for me instead of making me do the leg work too!

Comment: @Aylox Spelling it out in a moment ... Hold on :-)

Comment: That `[${char}]` idea is genius!

Comment: Goodness me that is a nice answer!

Comment: @DanielT thanks - added

Comment: Wow Raffa, you really went above and beyond on this!  Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this all, it's very helpful and is way more than I was hoping for!

Comment: Ended up using  $ grep ^"${char}". file.txt | cut -c 2-  because it worked better with the rest of the program, but your reply helped me a bunch. I was having a rough time with syntax for sed and awk so thanks again.